# Synonym for "turn around"

Tags: word-request, synonyms

In many contexts, "turn around" is used for cases when you "transform" something completely. E.g. "He turned around his life." I want a synonym for "turn around" in such contexts, but something which is stronger than "transform". Here is the sentence for which I need the synonym:

> This prospect turned out to be a key element that turned around our business.

Now, here "turn out" and "turn around" are giving a repetitive sound. Hence, I am looking for a synonym for "turn around".

Or else, if someone can suggest some other changes to this sentence, which would make the sentence more lively, please do so.

Comment: You've already "defined" ***to turn X around*** as ***to transform X*** in your first sentence. Why doesn't ***transform*** answer your needs?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Actually, I am looking for a stronger word than "transform". "Transform" doesn't sound as strong as "turn around". I've edited my question and mentioned the same requirement there.

Comment: I'd say claiming to have ***transformed*** a business is an exceptionally "strong" usage. Opinions may differ, obviously, but to my mind, ***turning a business around*** might mean little more than shifting from gradually declining annual profits to gradually increasing (or even just "static, stable") profits. But a small local company could be ***transformed*** into a global multinational, as we've seen often enough in recent decades.

Comment: (You could go for something like *...that **turbocharged** our business*, but that's getting a bit "poetic, hyperbolic". Besides which, that's what I'd call Off Topic "style advice".)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes. Actually, you are correct. "transform" does sound stronger. However, "turn around" sounds stronger in the sense that you become completely "opposite" to what you were before. "turn around" really emphasizes that, which "transform" does not. So, I am looking for a synonym with the sense of "transform" but emphasizing the aspect "becoming completely opposite".

Comment: If you want to emphasise that particular metaphoric allusion, just say something like *...that **completely** turned our business around*. Note that with or without the intensifying adverb, *[He] turned around the business* is relatively non-idiomatic (compared to *[He] turned the business around*).

Comment: To *really* focus on that specific allusion, how about [*We turned the business around **180 degrees** in the last six months.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22turned+the+business+around+180%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Wow!! That's an awesome suggestion. You should add that as answer.

Comment: Ty. I originally closevoted for lack of clarity (what's wrong with ***transform***?). But per previous comment, I'd say we're now well into Off Topic "writing advice" territory. Note that I *wouldn't* be saying that if your question had been focused on the placement of ***around*** in the example text.

Comment: You could replace *turned around* with something like ***saved***, ***rescued***, or ***restored***. However, it's not all clear if that's what you really mean. (And any thesaurus would result in those.) Something positive can also be "turned around" into something negative.

Comment: Still looking for a word synonymous to 'transform'?  Try this: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metamorphose

Answer (score 1):

We would generally use the following word order:

> He turned his life around.

Here are some alternatives that you could use:

> This propsect was the key insight resulting in our **reinventing** our business.
>
> This prospect allowed us to **rethink** and **reformulate** our business model.
>
> This prospect **revolutionized** our business.
>
> We **augmented** our business model with this prospect and it allowed us to **break new ground** and **make forward strides**.
>
> We **turned over a new leaf** with this prospect, and **reinvigorated** our business.

There are plenty of other ways to say this, as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider

> This prospect turned out to be a ***(pivotal) turning point*** for our business.

The idiomatic phrases are ***pivotal point/moment*** and ***turning point***, but I have come across ***pivotal turning point***, too.

A ***pivot*** is "a shaft or pin on which something turns" ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivot)) and ***pivotal*** is used mostly figuratively to mean:

> central and important: e.g. a pivotal figure/role/idea

A ***turning point*** is

> the time at which a situation starts to change in an important way:
>
> - The organization called the new regulations a turning point in the
>   campaign against smoking. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turning-point))

or

> a time at which a decisive change in a situation occurs, especially
> one with beneficial results.
>
> - This could be the turning point in Nigel's career. ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&biw=1715&bih=827&sxsrf=ALeKk02dXEguJ6JerM4sBAWevLlhHcCGuw%3A1611764473085&ei=-ZIRYLjlBLyp1fAPzK6tgAo&q=turning%20point%20meaning&oq=turning%20point%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgcIABBGEPkBMgYIABAHEB4yAggAMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgIIADoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoFCAAQkQI6BAgAEA1QpCtYmT1g2UpoAHACeACAAbMCiAGLDpIBBzMuOC4xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab))

Therefore, "a (pivotal) turning point" is a point in the development of that business after which nothing is the same, everything has changed for the better.